# Hash Tables vs Arrays MongoDB performance what implementation is faster?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I am studying the difference between hash tables and arrays, the verdict is that arrays are slower than hash tables when it coms to some operations like searching (query) o(n), inserting o(n), in mongo dB implementation see the code below a nested objects use arrays, is it a bad practice or a justified one, could this really affect the proformas also does mongo dB arrays any different when it comes to performance, compared to js arrays thanks for your time?

```js
db.inventory.insertMany([
   { item: "journal",
   qty: 25, tags: ["blank", "red"], 
   dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "notebook",
   qty: 50, 
   tags: ["red", "blank"],
   dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
```

Comment: I think the JavaScript arrays and MongoDB data arrays are different and have their purposes. JS arrays are used in programming - various purposes. MongoDB data array field is for storing data, related to the main document, and performing CRUD operations on that data efficiently. You can also use indexes on the MongoDB array fields for optimized querying in update, delete and red operations.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.